# How to create a nested dictionary from existing dictionary with set and list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, midi, markov-chains, mido

I have parsed a midi file, and I've successfully gotten a dictionary of notes broken up by instrument. An abbreviated example of this is `note_dict` below, truncated for the purposes of this question.

My end goal is to have a nested dictionary that provides me with the track name, then each possible note as a key, then a list of all possible "next" notes as values. The intent is to use this in as a [Markov chain in Foxdot](https://foxdot.org/docs/pattern-generators/), a python interface for music generation.

It should look something like:

```
{'track1': {note: [note1, note2, note3], note2: [note1, note2, note3]}, 'track2': {note: [note1, note2, note3], note2: [note1, note2, note3]}
```

Here is an example of what I have:

```
import itertools 

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return list(zip(a, b))

note_dict = {'Vocal': [-2, -2, -1, -2], 'Guitar': [1, 1, 4, 1, -2, 1]}

note_dict_updated = { track: [{ n for n in notes }, pairwise(notes), notes] for track, notes in note_dict.items() }
print(note_dict_updated)
```

This gives me the following, where the first set is all distinct notes, the list of tuples is a pairing of `(note, next note)`, and the last list is just a raw list of notes in order.

```
{'Vocal': [{-2, -1}, [(-2, -2), (-2, -1), (-1, -2)], [-2, -2, -1, -2]], 'Guitar': [{1, 4, -2}, [(1, 1), (1, 4), (4, 1), (1, -2), (-2, 1)], [1, 1, 4, 1, -2, 1]]}
```

I'd like the elements of the sets to act as keys, and when the first element of the tuple matches an element of the set, it is added to a list of values associated with the key.

My desired end result, based on `note_dict` above is:

```
{'Vocal': {-2: [-2, -1], -1: [-2]}, 'Guitar': {1: [1, 4, -2], 4: [1], -2: [1]}}
```

All that said, I am not locked into the method where I need to work with `note_dict_updated`. If there is a smarter way to get from `note_dict` to my desired end result, I'd love to hear.

***edit:*** I've updated my question a bit. The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62988610/13959910) worked for my initial example, but I believe there are issues when the list of notes in each value overlap. Hopefully, my updated desired end result will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop creates an intermediary dictionary of dictionary with inner keys and the same unique sets. This is then cleaned with a second a for-loop as shown here:

Input:

```
{'Vocal': [-2, -2, -1, -2], 'Guitar': [1, 1, 4, 1]}
```

Output:

```
{'Guitar': {1: [1, 4], 4: [1]}, 'Vocal': {-2: [-1, -2], -1: [-2]}}
```

Code:

```
#create a new dictionary of dictionary with inner keys and same unique sets

note_dict_updated={}
for key, value in note_dict.iteritems():
    note_dict_updated[key]={}
    for element in set(note_dict[key]):
        note_dict_updated[key][element]=list(set(note_dict[key]))

# remove the values (of not interest) from list values of inner keys 
for key, value in note_dict_updated.iteritems():
    comb=[]
    for lkey, lvalue in note_dict_updated[key].iteritems():
        for val in lvalue:
            if (val,lkey) in comb:
                try:
                    note_dict_updated[key][lkey].remove(lkey)
                except ValueError as e:
                    print ('Issue in key {} for subkey {}'.format(key,lkey))
        for val in lvalue:
            comb.append((lkey,val))
```

Comment: thanks! 
When running this for the actual dictionary (above 16k values), I get
`ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Your code works perfectly on small dictionaries, though. Do you have any recommendations to get around this concern with `remove()`?

Comment: I've added an exception handler that will print the offending key & subkey. It might help you to discern why the error is arising.